# How to select multiple rows of mysql table as a single row

Tags: mysql

I have member table like below

```
MemberID    Name     BookID
    1       ABC         10
    1       ABC         14
    2       XYZ         10
    3       PQR         14
```

I want to select a `MemberID` that contains both the `BOOKID 10 and 14` in single row.

**Expected Output:**

```
MemberID
1
```

I have tried below code but it doesnt work:

```
select MemberID from member where BookID IN (10,14)
```

Comment: you are putting in where condition BookId=(10,14), in this case you will get all member id..

Comment: I get empty result set when I use AND in where condition select MemberID from member where BookID=10 and BookID =14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT MemberID, GROUP_CONCAT(BookID) AS BookID
FROM member
GROUP BY MemberID
HAVING FIND_IN_SET(10, BookID) > 0 AND FIND_IN_SET(14, BookID) > 0
```

Here is the [`SQLFIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65604/1).

Another solution can be using `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT x.MemberID
FROM member x
INNER JOIN member y ON x.MemberID = y.MemberID
  AND x.BookID = 10
  AND y.BookID = 14
```

Here is the [`SQLFIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65604/5).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT` keyword

```
 select distinct MemberID from member where BookID
```

Comment: It returns empty result set

Comment: The answer above using groupby clause is the perfect answer for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is select distinct MemberID. Something like

```
SELECT  DISTINCT MemberID FROM member
WHERE BookID IN (10,14)
```

Assuming you want results for books with Id 10 or 12.

Comment: This will return all of them.

Comment: No I want results for books with ID 10 AND 12